# Can I get the word pronunciation data from Google AJAX Language API

Tags: ajax, google-translate

is there a way to get a word pronunciation data from Google AJAX language API? I couldn't find any reference. Is it available at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, try this:

http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=example&sl=en&tl=en

where "example" is the word you want the pronunciation for.